# How to find the respective element using xpath contains() function -selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is the html snippet

```
<div class="ext-cal-wk-ct">
   <table>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td><div>13</div></td>
               <td><div>14</div></td>
               <td><div>15</div></td>
           <tr>
           <tr>
               <td><div>Calender note WebElement[no 13]</div></td>
               <td><div>Calender note WebElement[no 14]</div></td>
               <td><div>Calender note WebElement[no 15]</div></td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

I want to find the respective element using xpath by the element no
for example:
if I use `contains(text(),'13')`--> WebElement no 13 should be returned
for `contains(text(),'14')`--> WebElement no 14 should be returned and so on

I have used two xpaths to find the elements individually but don't know how to connect them

`//div[@class='ext-cal-wk-ct']/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div[contains(text(),'13')]`

`//div[@class='ext-cal-wk-ct']/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div[contains(text(),'Tim Cook')]`

need some help on this

I want a xpath where I will pass the date and it will return me the calender note for that particular date

Answer (score 0):

basically, `contains` is for partial matching.

When you write

```
contains(text(),'13')
```

there are 2 matching nodes,

```
<div>13</div>
```

and

```
<div>WebElement no 13</div>
```

so I would suggest to use :

```
//div[@class='ext-cal-wk-ct']/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div[text(),'13']
```

to locate

```
<div>13</div>
```

or

```
//div[@class='ext-cal-wk-ct']/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div[text()='WebElement no 13']
```

to locate this :

```
<div>WebElement no 13</div>
```

Comment: actually "WebElement no 13" is a webElement like a calender note now I want a xpath where i will pass the date to get the note for that particular date. 
thats why I used `contains(text(),'13')`

Comment: so what does that mean ? did my answer resolves your query  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax by using contains in xpath

```
//tagname[contains(text(),'textname')]
```

I guess in your case you should consider exact match :

`<td><div>15</div></td>` : for this element

xpath =>      `//td/div[text()='13']`

and for this element : `<td><div>WebElement no 13</div></td>`

xpath =>  `//td/div[text()='WebElement no 13']`

i hope there is unique text in dom for given html snippet.